# Accessing friend data from Facebook JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, facebook

I am new to Swift and JSON and could use some quick help. My app has Facebook authentication and will read a list of your friends that have authorized the app as well. Everything logs correctly but I am unfamiliar with how to print the friend Id of each individual friend. Here is my code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                 parameters: ["fields": "id, name,friends, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"])
                .start(completionHandler: { (connection, result , error) -> Void in
                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(data)
```

And this is the data it logs for friends:

```
"friends": {
    data = (
        {
            id = 10104542348623278;
            name = "John Smith";
        },
```

But what I cannot figure out is how to print the id of each individual friend. This is what I have tried unsuccessfully.

```
for friend in data["friends"] {
    let friendId = data["friends"]["id"]
    print(friendId)
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `friends` is a Dictionary.
- `data` inside it is an Array of Dictionary.

  ```
  if let friendsData = data["friends"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

      if let friends = friendsData["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
          for friend in friends{
              print(friend["id"])
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It says 'any object is not convertible to string: any object, did you mean to use as! to downcast. But then when I do force downcast I get another error

Comment: try now...forgot the "?" optional.

Comment: If you're using only swift code, you should better use Any instead of AnyObject.